# Add up column using while not breaking other code

Tags: php, mysql

My connect to my database works fine so I will include just the code. What I am trying to do is create a sum of the total hours spent on a specific project. The code I have right now displays the comments all the comments from the last day the project was updated:

```
$query = "SELECT id, date,(select username from users where id = u.user_id) as     user, (select description from requests where id = u.request_id) as request, notes, hours from updates u where u.request_id=$rid and date(date) = (select max(date(date)) from updates where request_id = $rid) order by (select description from requests where id = u.request_id) asc";
```

This is how it is displayed on the web page:

[Click to see image of what is displayed on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJUKf.png)

The "test" code that I have that will add the total hours:

```
$query = "SELECT id, date,(select username from users where id = u.user_id) as user, (select description from requests where id = u.request_id) as request, notes, SUM(hours) as clienthours, hours from updates u where u.request_id=$rid and date(date) = (select max(date(date)) from updates where request_id = $rid) order by (select description from requests where id = u.request_id) asc
```

This is how it is display on the web page. Notice that all the other comments are gone except the first one of the day.
[Click to see image of what is display on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkyOm.png)

I tried adjusting the order of the query but it will send me errors and break the code. I haven't been able to find a solution and would appreciate any help I can get. I am not very advanced when it comes to PHP so my methods are odd and I am building off of someone else code. Any advice will help!

Thank you.

Comment: The way your linking to the various tables may cause all sorts of problems, try reading up about how to use JOIN for SQL tables.

Comment: You didn't show any PHP but in the loop for the first query just do `$total += $row['hours'];` then use `$total` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that the main issue with your second script is that you are trying to SUM a column which is returning one row, in SQL you can only return a SUM() when it is the only column in your SELECT.

The below should get around this and also will be more efficient for you by using joins (I've made the assumption that updates.request_id is the unique primary key)

```
SELECT up.id, up.date, us.username, description, notes,
 (SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM updates z WHERE z.request_id = up.request_id)
FROM updates up
INNER JOIN requests r ON u.request_id = r.id
INNER JOIN users us ON up.user_id = us.id
WHERE up.request_id = $rid AND
up.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM updates WHERE request_id = $rid)
ORDER BY r.description ASC;
```